# How to solve matrix eigenvalue equation which has a summation.

Tags: matrices, summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-equations

**General problem:**

If I have some $n \times n$ matrices $\mathsf{M}^\tau$, and column vectors (with $n$ rows) $X^\tau$ is there some mathematical tricks I can do to solve the eigenvalue equation $ \sum_\tau \mathsf{M}^\tau X^\tau = \sum_\tau E^\tau X^\tau$? If there was no summation I would do the usual trick of calculating $\det(\mathsf{M}^\tau - I_n E^\tau) = 0$ but not sure what to do here.

**My specific problem:**

I have the equation:

$$
\sum_\tau
\begin{pmatrix}  
A+2D & -iC^\tau & -2D & -iC^\tau\\
iC^\tau & B^\tau & -iC^\tau & 0\\
2D & -iC^\tau & -A-2D & -iC^\tau\\
-iC^\tau & 0 & iC^\tau & -B^\tau
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w \\ x^\tau \\ y \\ z^\tau
\end{pmatrix}
=
\sum_\tau
E^\tau
\begin{pmatrix}
w \\ x^\tau \\ y \\ z^\tau
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 and want to find $E^\tau$. $A,B^\tau,C^\tau$ and $D$ are known. The column vectors are unknown.

In these equations $\tau$ is just an index.

**Edit: More info:**

This is likely superfluous but I'll briefly explain where this equation comes from. Maybe it adds additional information which illuminates what kind of solution can be used.

I have a Hamiltonian in second quantisation representation as

$H = \sum_q \sum_\tau \Bigg\{ A c_q^\dagger c_q + B^\tau \beta_q^{\tau\dagger} \beta_q^\tau + C_q^\tau (c_q + c_q^\dagger )(\beta_{-q}^\tau - \beta_q^{\tau \dagger}) + D(2c_q^\dagger c_q + c_q c_{-q} + c_q^\dagger c_{-q}^\dagger) \Bigg\}$

where the $\beta$'s and $c$'s are creation/annihilation operators. I introduce a new operator $\gamma_q = \sum_\tau w c_q + x^\tau \beta_q^\tau + y c_{-q}^\dagger + z^\tau \beta_{-q}^{\tau \dagger}$ which diagonalises the Hamiltonian if it obeys the Heisenberg equation of motion $[\gamma_q,H]=E^\tau \gamma_q$. Crunching through this equation and representing the result in matrix form gives me the equation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the $X^{\tau}$'s and the $E^{\tau}$'s are both unknown.

One type of solution is found by removing the summation and assuming that $M^{\tau} X^{\tau} = E^{\tau} X^{\tau}$ holds for each individual term. That is, letting $(X^{\tau},E^{\tau})$ be an arbitrary eigenvector-eigenvalue pair of $M^{\tau}$ yields one solution.

Another type of solution is obtained with the Ansatz $X^{\tau} = X$ and $E^{\tau} = E$ (independent of $\tau$). Then it reduces to finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the sum $\sum_{\tau} M^{\tau}$.

I do not know how many other solutions there are. Perhaps it is also possible to pair-wise solutions, e.g. $M^1 X^1 = E^2 X^2$ and $M^2 X^2 = E^1 X^1$, or cyclic solutions $M^k X^k = E^{k+1} X^{k+1}$?

**EDIT**: Your specific problem looks a little more restricted in that parts of $X^{\tau}$ (namely w and y) are independent of $\tau$. At least the Ansatz $X^{\tau} = X$ should give you one solution here too.

Comment: Removing the summation would certainly be a neat solution, but in what circumstances can I justify this assumption? It may not help but I have edited my question to show where this equation comes from, perhaps that will shed some light on whether such a solution is permissible.

Comment: Removing the summation gives you one type of solution to the original equation. If finding some solutions is all you need, then no further justification is needed. If finding all solutions, or some specific type of solution, is needed, more work remains. When it comes to your specific equation, some components of $X^{\tau}$ seem to be independent of $\tau$, so then removing the summation may not work.